# Is it possible to call a component method in nuxt from a page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm starting to work with Vue.js and I'm using Nuxt.js. 
I've created a component (a snackbar) and inside this component I created a method "showSnackbar" that works passing 2 parameters: color and text.
So when I call showSnackbar(color,text), it appears.

But, I want to call this method from a page. Because I want to use this snackbar in some pages and I don't want to write the same code all the time, so that's the reason why I decided to create a component. But I can't call from a page the method inside this component.

And that's why I wonder if is it that possible to call a component method from a page (where of course I import the component)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There might be a couple of ways to do it, I would create a [plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/).

Then you have both `<snackbar/>` component for placement and a global API to call the invoking method `this.$snackbar.open({someOptions: '...'})`

**For example:**

Create a folder in `./plugins/snackbar` and place the following in:

`./plugins/snackbar/index.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import snackbar from "~/plugins/snackbar/snackbar";

Vue.use(snackbar);
```

This is for `nuxt.config.js`, to load globally. Which looks like:

```
  ...
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   ** Doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
   */
  plugins: ["~/plugins/snackbar/index.js"],
  ...
```

ok, now create

`./plugins/snackbar/snackbar.js`

This is the plugin which holds state for the component and acts as an event proxy

```
import snackbar from "~/plugins/snackbar/snackbar.vue";

const Plugin = {
  install(Vue, options = {}) {
    /**
     * Makes sure that plugin can be installed only once
     */
    if (this.installed) {
      return;
    }
    this.installed = true;

    /**
     * Create event bus
     */

    this.event = new Vue();

    /**
     * Plugin methods
     */
    Vue.prototype.$snackbar = {
      show(options = {}) {
        Plugin.event.$emit("show", options, true);
      }
    };

    /**
     * Registration of <snackbar/> component
     */
    Vue.component("snackbar", snackbar);
  }
};

export default Plugin;
```

and now...

`./plugins/snackbar/snackbar.vue`

Where the magic happens...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="snackbar">
      <div v-if="show" :class="['snackbar', 'box-shadow', type]">
        <slot>{{ options.text }}</slot>
      </div>
    </transition>

    <pre>options: {{ options }}</pre>
    <pre>show: {{ show }}</pre>
    <pre>type: {{ type }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import snackbar from "~/plugins/snackbar/snackbar";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    options: {
      text: "",
      type: ""
    },
    show: false,
    type: "",
    timer: 0
  }),
  beforeMount() {
    snackbar.event.$on("show", options => {
      this.options = options;
      this.type = options.type;
      this.show = true;
      this.close(this.options.closeWait || 3000);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    close(timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = false;
      }, timeout);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.snackbar {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  background-color: #F48024;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.snackbar.success {
  background-color: rgb(71, 244, 36);
}

.snackbar.danger {
  background-color: rgb(244, 36, 47);
}

.snackbar-enter-active {
  animation: snackbar-in 0.8s;
}
.snackbar-leave-active {
  animation: snackbar-in 0.8s reverse;
}
@keyframes snackbar-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.box-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
</style>
```

Then within any component/pages which uses it, you can place with `<snackbar/>`, and call the methods like:

```
this.$snackbar.show({
  text: "Hello, snackbar!",
  type: "success"
});
```

A working example of the above can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-oeo4h

Comment: And the magic happens! Thank you for your answer, very useful. It's worked perfectly and something new that I learned

Comment: np, glad it helped