# How to create a reusable Vuetify Snackbar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a reusable alert/snackbar component. I declared them like this:

**Snackbar.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-snackbar transition="true" timeout="2000" :show="`${show}`" :color="`${color}`" absolute top outlined right>
        <strong>
            {{ message }}
        </strong>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Snackbar',
    props: {
        show: String,
        color: String,
        message: String
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <v-snackbar transition="true" timeout="2000" :show="`${show}`" :color="`${color}`" absolute top outlined right>
        <strong>
            {{ message }}
        </strong>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Snackbar',
    props: {
        show: String,
        color: String,
        message: String
    }
}
</script>
```

I imported, and pass probs to them like so :

```
import Snackbar from '../../../components/Snackbar'

<Snackbar v-if="alert" color="alertColor" message="alertMessage" />
<Snackbar show="alert" color="alertColor" message="alertMessage" />
```

I've tried the 2 lines above, and these are the value of those 3 variables

- alert = `true`
- alertColor = `green`
- alertMessage = `create.vue?f4fe:631 DB error - insert_marketing_campaign: Duplicate entry 'TEST' for key 'MARKETING_CAMPAIGN_AK'`

Result

I see no error in console, but see no snackbar either. pls help

Comment: Could also make one instance of `<snackbar/>` which you place once within the layout/template/app.vue etc then invoke it with `this.$snackbar.show({...options...})` from anywhere, example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484558/is-it-possible-to-call-a-component-method-in-nuxt-from-a-page/57484984#57484984

Comment: That link above is too complicated and is not what I am using. No Nuxt here just basic vue

Comment: In order to avoid importing the Snackbar component everywhere, put it in the App level and use an EventBus to trigger it's value, type, and toggle from every other component you will need to call the snackbar from.

Comment: nuxt or not its still just a vue [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), that's generally how its done, @Muge yup like my example lol

Answer (score 1):

8!

You aren't passing props values correctly, you have to do this instead:

ps. for illustration, i added an event listener(update) to deal with a close button(remove if you dont want to use)

```vue
<Snackbar :show="alert" :color="alertColor" :message="alertMessage" v-on:update="alert = $event" />
```

**Snackbar.vue**

I changed a few things here too:

- the way you are using props in the attributes works, but if dont need to concatenate other values, keep it simple
- prop **show** must be Boolean
- added a *beautiful* button if you want to use
- v-model controls snackbar exhibition, but you can't use the prop **show** directly on v-model, that's why we have a computed property "**show2**"(very creative) that read(**get**) the value of prop **show** and **emit** a custom event "**update**" if you want to change it(**set**)

```vue
<template>
    <v-snackbar transition="true" timeout="2000" v-model="show2" :color="color" absolute top outlined right>
        <strong>
            {{ message }}
        </strong>
        <v-btn color="red" text @click="show2 = false">Close</v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
    color: String,
    message: String,
  },
  computed: {
    show2: {
      get() {
        return this.show;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: Are you sure we can’t simplify it a bit more ? Sometimes less is more …

Comment: @code-8 not that i'm aware of...  you can remove the close button and remove the v-on:update, but the computed property **show2** must exist with get and set(u can even remove the $emit part)

Answer (score 0):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71244492-vuex-snackbar-klfunf?file=/src/store/index.js

You can set up a global snackbar in your `App.vue` file and update it with `Vuex`. In your vuex store you set up an snackbar object and create a simple update mutation and show action.

```js
// store/index.js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    snackbar: { active: false, color: "", message: "", timer: 4000 }
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_SNACKBAR(state, snackbar) {
      state.snackbar = snackbar;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    showSnack({ commit }, { message, color, timer }) {
      commit("UPDATE_SNACKBAR", {
        active: true,
        color: color,
        message: message,
        timer: timer
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then in your `App.vue` you set it up like this

```html
<v-snackbar
   v-model="snackbar.active"
   :color="snackbar.color"
   :right="true"
   :bottom="true"
   :timeout="snackbar.timer"
>
   {{ snackbar.message }}
   <template #action="{ attrs }">
      <v-btn
         color="white"
         text
         v-bind="attrs"
         @click="snackbar.active = false"
      >
         Close
      </v-btn>
   </template>
</v-snackbar>
```

```js
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
   name: 'App',
   data: () => ({
      drawer: false,
   }),
   computed: {        
    ...mapState(["snackbar"])    
   }
}
</script>
```

Then you can trigger your snackbar from any component simply by doing this

```js
// views/Home.vue
this.$store.dispatch('showSnack', {
   message: 'Testing, main page.',
   color: 'green darken-1'
})

// views/About.vue
this.$store.dispatch('showSnack', {
   message: 'Hello from about!',
   color: 'red darken-1',
   timer: 2000
})
```